# WebRTC: Firefox often choses the worst ICE candidate?

Tags: firefox, webrtc

After deploying WebRTC functionality including audio/video I noticed that FireFox browsers overwhelmingly always pick the worst ICE candidate using the TURN server. 9/10 times it will go with that even with a perfectly good candidate using STUN over Full Cone NAT available.  Chrome always goes with the STUN option.  I've noticed this with other WebRTC apps as well like Google Hangouts.

Why is this?

Comment: file a bug against Firefox and provide hard data (about:webrtc and chrome://webrtc-internals).
That does not match my experience.

Comment: Firefox gives the lowest priority to TURN candidates and uses aggressive nomination (which basically means the highest priority candidate wins). So yes please file a bug here https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Core&component=WebRTC and we will have a look.